# Best Graph Drawing Algorithm For Hierarchical Data?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph, graph-drawing

I have a collection of directed *acyclic* graphs that are *nearly* trees, in the following sense: each graph has a *root*, and the vertices are organized into *levels* such that if *v*<sub>1</sub> and *v*<sub>2</sub> are vertices, then if the level of *v*<sub>1</sub> is less than the level of *v*<sub>2</sub>, then there is no edge from *v*<sub>2</sub> to *v*<sub>1</sub> in the graph, although there may be many edges from *v*<sub>1</sub> to vertices at the same or a greater level. For example, an expression tree, a function call graph, or a linear class hierarchy, would be examples of such graphs. Here is an example of such a graph:

```
              A1            
             /  \           A1 -> A4, A3
            /    \          A3 -> A2, A6, A7
          A4  A2--A3        A2 -> A6
              | \ / \
              A6 \_ A7
```

There are a plethora of graph-drawing algorithms, and I can't determine which is optimal for this situation. Some preliminary research indicates that algorithms for drawing Hasse diagrams might be appropriate, but it seems that the output of such algorithms isn't geared toward the type of data structures that I'm trying to model. There are also several algorithms for modeling hierarchical data, but I'm not sure which would balance ease of implementation with efficiency. One problem with the former approach is that these graphs have a root, as well as a direction. If possible, the algorithm would support *cyclic* graphs, and minimize the number of numeric computations, but this isn't necessary. For these reasons, I would prefer to avoid force-directed algorithms, and if possible, the GraphViz algorithms such as *dot*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really an answer, but it was too long for a comment.

How do your graphs differ from a general directed acyclic graph?

A DAG doesn't have to have a root, but I think that makes little difference to drawing the graph.

As far as levels go, for any DAG, it is possible to define a function level(v) such that for any edge v<sub>i</sub> → v<sub>j</sub>, level(i) ≤ level(j). A trivial level function is the index of the vertex in a topological order of the vertices. Another one is the length of the longest path from the root to the vertex.

The Reingold-Tilford tree-drawing algorithm draws ordered trees (that is, trees where the edges from a vertex are ordered). Your examples suggest that your graphs are not ordered, and indeed that the main issue you face is finding an edge-ordering which minimizes edge-crossing. So possibly this is the problem you are looking to solve. (It's not an easy problem.)

`dot` actually does pretty well with DAGs, in my experience, although it sometimes needs a bit of a helping hand. In particular, if you know the level of each vertex, you can make a subgraph for each level with the attribute `rank = "same"'. (See [this example](http://www.graphviz.org/content/sdh).)

Comment: I apologize for responding belatedly; I didn't realize that there was an additional answer. I think that you are correct: using a tree-drawing algorithm in addition to an edge-crossing algorithm would be the best option. This seems to be the best answer, since it clarified the problem by suggesting that it be solved by combining a tree-drawing algorithm with an algorithm to minimize edge-crossings.

Answer (score 1):

If it's exactly a tree, then I have seen this [Reingold–Tilford Tree drawing algorithm](http://bl.ocks.org/4063550) work very well before.

BTW, I feel the decision to allow node A2 to 'go up' to the same level as its ancestor isn't really helping that much.

In stead I would allow a node to go down further instead of going up.
The example could be drawn better as shown below in my opinion.

```
          A1            
         /  \           A1 -> A4, A3
        /    \          A3 -> A2, A6, A7
      A4     A3         A2 -> A6
            / | \
          A2  |  A7
            \ |
             A6
```

This way you don't even need to label edge direction.
[Did I misunderstand your original diagram? I think there is no edge between A2 and A7 right?]

Comment: The problem is that the graphs lie somewhere between a tree, and a full acyclic graph. If the former, I could use an algorithm like the one you suggested; if the latter, I could use the linear-time optimization of the Sukiyama algorithm, or something similar. You're right that allowing a node to "go up to" the same level as its ancestory probably isn't helpful; for the data structures I'm working with, that would result in transforming them as you suggested, but restrict the class of graphs that could be drawn.